# Extend Html.DropDownList with a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to extend the DropDownList to accept any type of list .

The code that I have is for enums. I want to use it for whatever list not only enums.

```
   public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(
                   this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                   Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                   TEnum selectedValue)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
            var items = from value in values
                        select new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = value.ToString(),
                            Value = value.ToString(),
                            Selected = value.Equals(selectedValue)
                        };
            return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, items);
        }
```

how to refactor this code so it can be used for all type of lists like ( vehicle type, make models, year ..etc)

Comment: Your could have parameters `IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField` and in the method use `new SelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField)` to build the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Side note: There is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` (its ignored by `SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor`).

Comment: thank you. My point is that I want my helper to use all type of lists not Enums only

Comment: Which is exactly what adding those parameters will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code working by using the code below :

```
  public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            List<dynamic> selectedValue)
        {
                           var items = from value in selectedValue
                        select new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = value.ToString(),
                            Value = value.ToString()
                        };
            return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items);
        }
```